# Correct use of Word Phrase

Tags: usage, phrase-choice

> It was like using a watch that runs slow. (It=Egyptian calendar)

What was the Egyptian calendar similar to?

1. using a watch that runs slow
2. a watch that runs slow

Which one is correct?

Comment: Tell us what you think and why, and we'll tell you if you're on the right track ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Actually neither is correct, it should be

> like a watch that runs slow**ly**

**slowly** is the adverb that modifies the verb **runs**

For your phrase examples, the Egyptian calendar is similar to both

> The Egyptian calendar was similar to using a watch that runs slowly

in its usage, "Using the Egyptian calendar" is implied, or

> The Egyptian calendar was similar to a watch that runs slowly.

describes how the Egyptian calendar itself runs.
Better phrasing might be

> The Egyptian calendar was like a slow running watch.

using the simile **like** to make an analogous comparison.

Comment: Actually *slow* might be just fine, as a [flat adverb](http://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/flat-adverbs-are-exceeding-fine).

Comment: In the specific case of a watch or clock, it's perfectly acceptable to say "a watch that runs slow" or "a watch that runs fast". A clock that runs slow/fast and a clock that runs quickly/slowly are completely different meanings. In the first, the indicated time does not match the actual time. In the second, the perceived or relative time is passing slowly or quickly.