# Slowly running watch or slow running watch

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

My question is:

> "The Egyptian Calendar was like a -------watch."

I think the answer "slowly running watch" is grammatically right. But on the other hand, "slow running watch" is most common in use nowadays. I would like to know which answer you prefer.

Comment: Related answer: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/82132/9161

Comment: Also if you're interested in a very in-depth description of the difference between using the adjective and the adverb: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/46391/9161

Comment: How about `It was like a watch that runs slow.`

Answer (score 3):

"Slow-running" is a [*compound adjective*](http://www.grammar.com/compound-adjectives-a-long-list/), and so the "slow" part is not an adverb modifying the [participle](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/adjective-and-verb-placement/) "running", but instead two adjectives that combine to form a more complex adjective.  Other examples of this:

> Behind the house there ran a *quick-flowing* stream.
>
> Mary was famous for her *slow-cooked* pork stew.

You could describe it as a "watch that runs slowly", but it sounds more natural to me to say it "runs *slow*".

Comment: Did u mean both are acceptable answers?

Comment: I  don't think you meant to say that "slow-running" is modifying "running".

Comment: The "fast-moving" example isn't necessarily the most illuminating, since the adverb from "fast" is "fast" :-)

Comment: @psmears  Er, yeah.  Good point.  Edited.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best wording would be, "It was like a slow-running watch". In the case of a watch, slow describes the fact that it constantly loses time and falls behind. Worded another way, you might say, "my watch constantly runs slow." You wouldn't say, "my watch constantly runs slowly."